# Symfony PHP - How to filter date with timezone?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, timezone, api-platform.com

I want to filter data in PHP.

I added date filter `#[ApiFilter(DateFilter::class, properties: ['createdAt'])]`.

I sent dates like `createdAt.before=02-09-2022` and `createdAt.after=2022-07-10` and got data like this:

```
id   createdAt                   name
1    2022-08-23T05:05:45+00:00   Jow    
2    2022-07-19T01:22:31+00:00   Lily     
3    2022-07-10T13:05:18+00:00   Ran  
4    2022-07-10T04:00:00+00:00   Viki
```

Now, I want to filter with timezone. for example- to send the dates
`createdAt.before=02-09-2022T13:00:00+00:00` and `createdAt.after=2022-07-10T13:00:00+00:00`
and get a different list:

```
id   createdAt                   name
1    2022-08-23T05:05:45+00:00   Jow    
2    2022-07-19T01:22:31+00:00   Lily     
3    2022-07-10T13:05:18+00:00   Ran
```

The user Viki does not appear because his timezone before `T13:00:00+00:00`

How can I do it with that ApiFilter?

Thank you

Comment: Please provider more context/code. It's hard to image what you try to achieve and how you're doing it

Comment: I added more explanation

Comment: use same format for filter datetime : like `createdAt.after=2022-07-10T13:00:00+00:00` and  `createdAt.before=2022-09-02T13:00:00+00:00`,  then all of your times on UTC time zone. I think your filter work correctly, see again your dates. (Viki ignored because created at 4:00 and your filter start after 13:00 on same day)

Comment: It didn't work for me. It returns me all items